# Does publishing a paper in a fake journal get someone in trouble?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am a young graduate student in Egypt. I have published few papers in high ranking journals in my field. One of the professors in my department is constantly publishing papers in these fake journal that accept a paper in a couple of days in exchange of money. He practically publishes a new paper every week. Universities here don't know much about fake journals and they recognise any paper as long as its published in journal with impact factor without knowing that some of these journals have fake impact factors. Also, his papers basically talk about the same thing and he keeps changing the title and spinning the content. Anyway this guy is constantly getting honoured for his research even though he has never published a paper in an honourable journal and he has just been made the head of the department I am in. I am not bitter but I just think its not fair and I don't know what to do about it. I am afraid if I say something he may cause a problem for me.

Comment: What is your question? It does not seem to be your titular question. (Please make it something other than “what can I do?“)

Comment: See also: [Does publishing in journals known as “predatory” hurt one's reputation?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49746/7734) and [How do I complain to chair if my advisor regularly writes to scam journals to get tenure?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15547/7734)